# How are bash variables containing a file path with non-ascii characters and spaces used as input for commands, cat, exiftool, etc.?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I have set a variable:

`myvar='/home/user/shares/D/iPhoto\ Library\ Main.migratedphotolibrary/Data.noindex/2002/102008\ \ name\ lname\ event/PICT0002_2_face0.jpg'`

Then tried to cat this variable:

`cat ${myvar}`
with the following result:

> cat: '/home/user/shares/D/iPhoto': No such file or directory cat:
> 'Library': No such file or directory cat:
> 'Main.migratedphotolibrary/Data.noindex/2002/102008': No such file
> or directory cat: '': No such file or directory cat: 'name': No such
> file or directory cat: 'lname': No such file or directory cat:
> event/PICT0002_2_face0.jpg: No such file or directory

`cat "${myvar}"`
with the following result:

> cat: '/home/user/shares/D/iPhoto\ Library
> Main.migratedphotolibrary/Data.noindex/2002/102008\ \ name\ lname
> event/PICT0002_2_face0.jpg': No such file or directory

Using the contents of myvar as direct input into cat, it works and the file contents are output correctly:

`cat /home/user/shares/D/iPhoto\ Library\ Main.migratedphotolibrary/Data.noindex/2002/102008\ \ name\ lname\ event/PICT0002_2_face0.jpg`

> <the file contents are output here>

How can I assign a file path to a variable and use cat (or exiftool, etc.) to output the contents of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the variable, don't use backslashes in single quotes.

```
myvar='/home/user/shares/D/iPhoto Library Main.migratedphotolibrary/Data.noindex/2002/102008  name lname event/PICT0002_2_face0.jpg'
```

Or, use backslashes but no quotes:

```
myvar=/home/user/shares/D/iPhoto\ Library\ Main.migratedphotolibrary/Data.noindex/2002/102008\ \ name\ lname\ event/PICT0002_2_face0.jpg
```

Both of them set the variable to the same value. Then, use double quotes when using the variable:

```
cat "$myvar"
```